# Sqlite: alter table add foreign key error

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, alter-table

This is really silly but I can't see where I am making the mistake: I am trying to add a foreign key to an existing table (sqlite3) with this sql statement:

```
ALTER TABLE tblDetail ADD FOREIGN KEY (master_id) REFERENCES tblMaster(id)
```

I get this error: `near "FOREIGN": syntax error:`

I can't see what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: `The only schema altering commands directly supported by SQLite are the "rename table" and "add column" commands`. See this link -
https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer